# How do I get turtle to move based on input in Python 3?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am writing a program that needs input in the console to control where a turtle goes on the screen. For example, if the user of the program types `w` in the console, and presses enter, the turtle should move forward 30 units. If the user types `a`, the turtle should turn left 45 degrees, etc.

I wrote some functions and used an infinite `while` loop for the program. It looks like this:

```
def movemattfd():
    matt.fd(30)

def movemattlt():
    matt.lt(45)

def movemattrt():
    matt.rt(45)

def movemattbk():
    matt.back(30)

def movematt():
    while True:
        input()
        if input() == 'w':
            movemattfd()

        if input() == 'a':
            movemattlt()

        if input() == 'd':
            movemattrt()

        if input() == 's':
            movemattbk()

def main():
    windowHeight = 500
    windowWidth = 500
    turtle.screensize(windowWidth, windowHeight, None)
    movematt()

main()
```

The program works, except when I enter `w` in the console, it takes at least 2 entries to get my turtle to move forward. It takes even more when I try to turn my turtle right.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should learn about extracting result into separate objects and [`elif`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) keyword

Comment: why do you need first `input()` right after `while True:` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `input()` prompts for a new entry from the user.

What your code does is, for every set of 5 entries:

- discard the first entry
- check if the second entry is `'w'` then move forward
- check if the third entry is `'a'` then move left
- check if the fourth entry is `'s'` then move right
- check if the fifth entry is `'d'` then move back

You should assign the first `input()` to a variable, then check with that.
Use `elif` to avoid checking other characters if it already satisfies one.

```
while True:
    entry = input()
    if entry == 'w':
        movemattfd()

    elif entry == 'a':
        movemattlt()

    elif entry == 'd':
        movemattrt()

    elif entry == 's':
        movemattbk()
```